# boost member function pointers

Tags: c++, class, boost, member

I am very new to the boost libraries.

I was trying to accomplish something for a graphical program, by binding the callbacks passed
to glutDisplayFunc(), etc to a single class.

I wanted to accomplish this without having some constant global class object.

To explain in code:

```
class CallbackHolder {
public:
    void dostuff(void) {
        // etc.
    }
};
void bind() {
    glutIdleFunc((new CallbackHolder())->dostuff);
}
```

I know this is possible through the usage of boost::bind and boost::function.

One issue I did see however was converting the boost::function back to a normal function pointer.

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot convert `boost::function` to a normal function pointer. You must use a regular plain function as a callback, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert from `boost::function` to a normal function pointer, and you can't convert from a member function pointer to a normal function pointer. There are workarounds for functions accepting callback where you can provide user data.

Unfortunately the glut interface doesn't let you provide user data. This means you're stuck with the ugliest solution, using a global variable and a normal function.

```
class CallbackHolder {
  public:
    void dostuff(void) {
      // etc.
    }
};

CallbackHolder * g_callbackHolder = NULL;

void call_callback_holder(void) {
   if(g_callbackHolder) g_callbackHolder->dostuff();
}

void bind() {
   g_callbackHolder = new CallbackHolder();
   glutIdleFunc( &call_callback_holder );
}
```

Comment: Darn. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to do this, as source code can get really ugly like that. Thanks anyway.